# Installation of Chromium in Kali Linux - Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate

Tags: kali-linux, chromium

```
# apt install chromium

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package chromium is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, is only available from another source

E: Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate
```

How can I fix it?

[image: Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate]

Comment: For what purpose to you need Chromium on Kali? I don't want to sound harsh but it seems that Kali is not the right distribution for you if you can't install chromium. Kali does not contain the same repositories as other linux distributions which is why you get that error

Comment: @EricF Your comment is incorrect. That is not the reason for the `E: Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate` error message in Kali Linux and in other Debian-based OSs generally.

Comment: Reviewers: Too broad is not the correct reason for closing this question which is about a simple package management error. A more correct reason for closing it would be because of a non-reproducible user error in Kali Linux.

Comment: Reviewers: "Unclear" is not the correct reason for closing this question which is about confusion caused by two completely different packages in the Kali default repositories which have similar names.

Answer (score 1):

The Chromium web browser package is named *chromium-browser*, not chromium in Kali Linux. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed Chromium as well on Kali 2020 and i did this to get it:

Add debian repository to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
```

The run update:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then install Chromium:

```
sudo apt install chromium chromium-l10n
```

It worked fine for me, maybe that’s not the best solution but at least it works.